# "dann" followed by "wenn" confusion

Tags: sentence-structure

I have the sentence

> Ich fahre gerne, aber nicht dann, wenn viel Verkehr ist.

Translating this seems very simple - *I like to drive, but not when there is lots of traffic*.

I'm confused though.

I know that "dann" in German normally means *then* or *afterwords* but that would make no sense in this context.

What is the purpose of dann in this sentence?

Comment: But *"dann"* does mean *then* here. Think of the the sentence as something like "I like to drive, but not **then** when there is lots of traffic", which is bad English, but you get the idea...

Comment: Translate that *dann* as *right then* and you get the picture.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, *dann* means *then* here. The purpose of *dann* is to put an emphasis on the constraint when the speaker does not like to drive.

You also could say the german sentence as

> Ich fahre gerne, aber nicht, wenn viel Verkehr ist.

This sentence will work, too. And it is the (literal) equivalent to your translation.

As mentioned in the comments, you also could translate the sentence to "I like to drive, but not **then** when there is a lot of traffic." Of course, this is bad English, but it shows the principle.

Comment: The *dann* may even be further emphasized: *genau dann*.

Comment: I'd argue it's bad German, too. Not as bad as the English equivalent, but completely redundant.

Comment: @Janka "genau dann" is technically not emphasis, but restriction to the point of exclusion. It's the usual translation of "if and only if" at least in mathematical texts.

Comment: "I like to drive, but not **at times** when (...)" would be a better english equivalent.